# 401 from vulnerability DB sync during trial

Tags: jfrog-xray

I just started a 30 day trial of Artifactory Pro and Xray on prem, stood up using docker-compose.

Most functionality is working fine, however when I try to sync the Xray vulnerability DB through the UI, it fails. Looking at the xray server service log I see:

2021-08-03T08:54:44.091Z [33m[jfxr ][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [f1000c9d14bbcc48] [updates_job:389               ] [main                ] Updates worker id 0 failed to download updates from https://jxray.jfrog.io/api/v1/updates/onboarding?version=3.25.1:  failed to get online updates
--- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/internal/jobs/scanner/scanner_job.go:793 (DownloadOnlineUpdates) ---
Caused by: Failed to access :https://jxray.jfrog.io/api/v1/updates/onboarding?version=3.25.1 return status code : 401
2021-08-03T08:54:44.091Z [33m[jfxr ][0m [1m[31m[ERROR][0m [f1000c9d14bbcc48] [updates_job:341               ] [main                ] failed to Download online updates
--- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/internal/jobs/updates_job.go:397 (UpdatesJob.downloadUpdateUrlsAndLastUpdateTime) ---
Caused by: failed to get online updates
--- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/internal/jobs/scanner/scanner_job.go:793 (DownloadOnlineUpdates) ---
Caused by: Failed to access :https://jxray.jfrog.io/api/v1/updates/onboarding?version=3.25.1 return status code : 401
2021-08-03T08:55:01.076Z [33m[jfxr ][0m [34m[INFO ][0m [                ] [samplers:327                  ] [main                ]

I get a similar response if I switch to offline sync and run the offline update:

~/src/artifactory  ❯ jfrog xr offline-update --license-id=**[redacted for posting]** --version=3.25.1
[Info] Getting updates...
[Error] Response: Server response: 401 Unauthorized

I'm assuming this is a licensing problem? Any suggestions please? - I'm assuming the xray trial includes access to the vulnerability DB?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the Xray trial license not being added correctly as 401 means license validation is failing at the JFrog end. Kindly confirm if the Xray trial license is added correctly under the UI --> Administration --> License | Xray trial license. Also, refer to this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-overcome-issue-when-xray-online-db-sync-fails-with-401/) for more insights.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the license is working locally at least - if I remove it, I can't access any of the Xray pages, if I reapply it, I can - so it seems to be being applied properly enough for the local services to recognise it. However I still get a 401 on trying to sync the db. I've tried the curl test (from within the containers running the xray server and xray router - and I get the successful 'pong' response.

Comment: @Justin Yes issue is with the license not being recognized. I think if it is a trial license there could some issue but as mentioned a new license worked so i think issue is fixed

Comment: Unfortunately the second license now is no longer working, and the sync job has stalled - now getting a 401 on trying to restart. Luckily I have a copy of the offline files. But I won't be easily able to keep the server in sync.

Comment: I think you should reach JFrog Support and check the license validity :)

Comment: I did and all they did was point me here! Its a great trial experience.....

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the license. I signed up for another trial, and used the xray license on my existing cluster. It initially failed in the same way, but shortly afterwards I was able to do an offline download (and when that worked, I tried an online sync which did work).